# Syncfusion RTE duplicates image on paste

Tags: webforms, syncfusion

The problem is when I copy and paste an image from "Paint" to the Syncfusion RTE it duplicates that image for some reason.

Using ej1 Version=18.3450.0.35 in Asp Net Web Forms

I've tried to update Syncfusion to the latest version but it didn't help.

Checked the clipboard and it has only one file, as expected.

**Replicated that in the official Synfusion Demo:**
https://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/richtexteditor/inlinetoolbar.aspx

**Works well in another Syncfusion demo:**
https://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/richtexteditor/paste-cleanup.aspx

I've tried to put the same RTE as in the second (working) demo but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas will be appreciated!!!

.aspx file

[image]

c# RTE initialization and tools

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing 'html' from the 'style' section in the RTE innerHTML.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue is fixed in your mentioned version “18.3.0.35” in RTE, so kindly ensure this after clearing NuGet and browser cache in your sample.

Please refer to the following release notes.

https://help.syncfusion.com/js/release-notes/v18.3.0.35?type=all#ejrte-bug-fixes

We have also attached a simple sample in this version for your reference where pasting images from paint is working fine.

https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/fkjqifbh